Translate help: 아 나처럼 쓰는거 아니야???ㅋㅋ
완전 오늘 (positive)이네
아 나처럼 쓰는거 아니야???ㅋㅋ
I am reading it as:

today's totally positive


ah using/saying [positive phrase] isn't like me right???ㅋㅋ

context: past couple of days he had bad luck, I've seen a fan account known for translations translate it to "ah you’re not using that expression like how i do???" but that doesn't feel entirely correct to me with the context of him having a terrible couple of days to then it being a positive day. would love to know others thoughts!!
나 - me
처럼 - like/as, showcasing similarity
쓰다 - to use/to write
아니다 - to not be
~는거 - shorted form for 는 것
~야/이야 - informal casual speech ending for nouns.
does 는거 not having a space making a difference or is that just text shortening?

You're on the right track with your interpretation! Let's break it down a bit more carefully to clarify:
완전 오늘 (positive)이네: This part is saying "Today is totally positive" or "Today's really positive." Here, the speaker is emphasizing how the day is going well after a rough patch, so it's an expression of positive surprise or a shift in mood.
아 나처럼 쓰는거 아니야???ㅋㅋ: This part is where there's some playful questioning. The speaker is essentially saying, "Ah, you're not using that expression like I do, are you???"
Here’s why:
나처럼 means "like me" or "in my way."
쓰는거 is short for 쓰는 것 (the thing that you use), and here, it's referring to the act of using the expression or phrase.
아니다 is "not to be," so 아니야 means "isn't it?" in casual speech. It’s not an outright question, but more like a rhetorical one or a playful remark.
ㅋㅋ indicates laughing, making it lighthearted.
In this context, the speaker is playfully asking if the other person is using the phrase "positive" in the same way they would. It's a bit of self-deprecation, as if the speaker is surprised that they're using such an upbeat expression after a series of bad days. The person might feel that it's not their usual way to express things, and is asking if the other person noticed that.
On the "는거" part:
The "는거" is indeed a shortened form of "는 것" (which means "the thing that is [verb]"), and the lack of space is a form of casual texting shorthand in Korean, especially common in informal contexts like chatting.
The lack of a space doesn't change the meaning significantly—it's just a form of abbreviation for efficiency or style in casual writing.
Final thoughts:
Given the context you provided, the fan translation to "Ah, you’re not using that expression like how I do???" fits well enough, though it may feel slightly more "playful" or less formal than you might expect in an everyday situation. Your understanding of "Today’s totally positive" is spot on, and the second part shows some humor and surprise at using a positive expression after a bad couple of days.
So, your interpretation of it being a playful remark about the use of the positive phrase seems pretty accurate!
